# How to insert array of strings in postgres using raw query in elixir

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I am trying to insert into the postgres using Elixir Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query, the query consists of array of tags which are strings. However it does inset into postgres, but not as a list of strings, but a single string. 
i.e. if tags contains ["abc","xyz"], it inserts in postgres as abcdef and not as array.

Important to mention, i am not using schema or migrations. Simple raw queries.

Map that needs to be inserted in postgres

```
  response_map=  %{"description" => "des33", "id" => 158,
  "inserted_at" => "2017-06-09T10:19:03.904572", "tags" => ["abc","xyz"],
  "title" => "test 1", "updated_at" => "2017-06-09T10:19:03.904578"}
```

Code that i use

```
%{"description" => desc, "id" => id, "title" => title, "tags" =>  tags}=response_map
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo,"insert into test values ('#{id}','#{title}','#{desc}','#{tags}')")
```

Comment: Does `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query` know about Postgres array types? This is a Postgres specific feature, and if the query builder / SQL client doesn't know about this, it won't know how to treat it correctly.

Comment: @HoriaComan so what do you think, how should i insert an array,

Comment: IDK, that's up to you. You could make tags be a json/jsonb type, of the form `{ "tags": [ list of tags ] }`. If you send it a serialized JSON object postgres will be smart enough to transform it into a JSON field, rather than leave it as  a string.

Comment: Ecto supports PostgreSQL Arrays just fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

**You should never use string interpolation in queries.** You're opening yourself to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries and you'll fix the SQL injection as well as make this work with arrays:

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo, "insert into test values ($1, $2, $3, $4)", [id, title, desc, tags])
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is what i am getting after the above code

(ArgumentError) Postgrex expected a binary, got ["abc", "xyz"]. Please make sure the value you are passing matches the definition in your t
able or in your query or convert the value accordingly.

Comment: What is the type of the fourth column in PostgreSQL? It should be an Array.

Comment: Can you post the output of running `\d test` from `psql` connected to your database? (That should print the schema of the table.) I just tested this and it works for me when the column is of type `text[]`.

Comment: tags        | character varying(255)[]

Comment: Can you add the complete output to the question?

Comment: `Column    |            Type             |                     Modifiers                      
`-------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------`---
 `id          | integer                     | not null default `nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass)
 `title       | character varying(255)      | 
 `description | character varying(255)      | 
 `tags        | character varying(255)[]    | 
 `inserted_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 `updated_at  | timestamp without time zone | not null
`Indexes:
 `  "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)